# How can I increment a variable with value of another variable in JasperReports?

Tags: ireport

This is existing question, but I'd like to know if I can do simple math calculation with variables in iReport, i.e.:

I have 12 variables named

- MONTH1_end_total
- MONTH2_end_total
- MONTH3_end_total

  ...
- MONTH12_end_total

All variables are of type `java.math.BigDecimal`.

---

**My question is**: can I create a `GRAND_total` variable in which I will use simple math add calculation like:

`GRAND_total = MONTH1_end_total + MONTH2_end_total + MONTH3_end_total`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. 
just use the simple math function like, 
`GrandTotal=MONTH1_end_total.add(MONTH2_end_total.add(MONTH3_end_total ))..`
and so on

Regards,
Gopinagh.R